# Punctuation of sentence ending with the word "period" for emphasis

Tags: syntactic-analysis, punctuation

I really enjoyed *The Dark Knight Rises* and want to send a grammatically correct tweet about it. Unfortunately correct punctuation of the following eludes me:

> In other news The Dark Knight Rises was better than The Dark Knight.
>   Not just a good super hero or action movie just a great movie, period.

What is the correct punctuation before the word "period?" Am I correct in using a comma or should an ellipsis or emdash be used instead?

Comment: "grammatically correct tweet" - now there's an idea. I would probably put "... great movie. End of." Which is twitterese for the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, questions on correct grammar and punctuation aren't on-topic at Writers.SE. I'm closing this; English.SE might want it though.

Comment: Better punctuation (and spelling): In other news, The Dark Knight Rises was better than The Dark Knight; not only a good superhero/action movie but a great movie, period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've punctuated it correctly, period.

NOAD agrees with us:

[image]

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/period) lists this usage as a third meaning of the word, with the qualifier `SPOKEN`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> In other news The Dark Knight Rises was better than The Dark Knight. Not just a good super hero movie or a good action movie, but a great movie, period.

It's still not grammatically correct as a whole, but it's good for every day language.

Answer (score 1):

When ending a thought with the word *period* for emphasis, you can precede it with a comma followed by the word *period* and then a period to end the sentence, OR you could end the first sentence without emphasis and a period, and then start a new one-word sentence with the word *period* capitalized and then a period for punctuation.

Examples:

> I think you've punctuated it correctly, period.
>   I think you've punctuated it correctly. Period.
>
> You are not going out tonight, period.
>   You are not going out tonight. Period.
>
> He is the sole owner of the trademark, period.
>   He is the sole owner of the trademark. Period.

Answer (score 0):

In other news, The Dark Knight Rises was better than The Dark Knight. Not just a good super-hero movie, or a good action movie—a good movie, period.